# Stuck on Android API 29 compatible network connection

Tags: android

You should check initial discussion on https://gist.github.com/PasanBhanu/730a32a9eeb180ec2950c172d54bb06a on.

Basically we were working a simple to use solution for checking network on android app, which can gracefully replace now deprecated `NetworkInfo` classes, without disrupting codeflow for legacy apps. The problem is only when switching to wifi, not when switching to cellular.

Main working code part:

```java
// Network Check
public void registerNetworkCallback()
{
    try {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkRequest.Builder builder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();

        connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(builder.build(),new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                        Variables.isNetworkConnected = true; // Global Static Variable
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onLost(Network network) {
                        Variables.isNetworkConnected = false; // Global Static Variable
                    }
                }

        );
        Variables.isNetworkConnected = false;
    }catch (Exception e){
        Variables.isNetworkConnected = false;
    }
}
```

The problem is when we switch to wifi, It for some reason makes a call to onLost after making call to onAvailable. Therefore setting value on static variable to false. Even when network is connected.

Here is a debug log on when network is switched to wifi:

```
2019-11-23 16:54:29.136 8416-8459/com.example.simplenetwork D/FLABS:: onAvailable
2019-11-23 16:54:29.136 8416-8459/com.example.simplenetwork D/FLABS:: onCapabilitiesChanged
2019-11-23 16:54:29.136 8416-8459/com.example.simplenetwork D/FLABS:: onLinkPropertiesChanged
2019-11-23 16:54:29.136 8416-8459/com.example.simplenetwork D/FLABS:: onBlockedStatusChanged
2019-11-23 16:54:29.307 8416-8459/com.example.simplenetwork D/FLABS:: onLosing

2019-11-23 16:54:29.325 8416-8459/com.example.simplenetwork D/FLABS:: onCapabilitiesChanged
2019-11-23 16:54:29.371 8416-8459/com.example.simplenetwork D/FLABS:: onLost

2019-11-23 16:54:29.959 8416-8459/com.example.simplenetwork D/FLABS:: onLinkPropertiesChanged
2019-11-23 16:54:29.975 8416-8459/com.example.simplenetwork D/FLABS:: onLinkPropertiesChanged
2019-11-23 16:54:30.972 8416-8459/com.example.simplenetwork D/FLABS:: onLinkPropertiesChanged
2019-11-23 16:54:31.693 8416-8459/com.example.simplenetwork D/FLABS:: onLinkPropertiesChanged
2019-11-23 16:54:32.053 8416-8459/com.example.simplenetwork D/FLABS:: onCapabilitiesChanged
```

I am trying adding additional checks in `onCapabilitiesChanged()` but so far nothing is resolving things without breaking other thing.

You can check complete code(and related progress/discussion) on https://gist.github.com/PasanBhanu/730a32a9eeb180ec2950c172d54bb06a

My version of code( which contains complete debug process ) as a clean separate project just for testing this, is on https://gist.github.com/Abhinav1217/0ff6b39e70fa38379d61e85e09b49fe7 .

PS: Can someone suggest better title for this question, something which would be more logical?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tldr: Use `registerDefaultNetworkCallback` instead of `registerNetworkCallback` for simple connectivity solution.

I finally opened a ticket to Google Android bug tracker. They explained why `registerNetworkCallback` works that way, For simple internet connectivity stuff They told me to use `registerDefaultNetworkCallback` instead. There are several more options discussed on the original gist  https://gist.github.com/PasanBhanu/730a32a9eeb180ec2950c172d54bb06a Thanks to the awesome community at github and stackoverflow.